# Dealing with fragmentation in a memory pool?

Tags: c++, memory, pool, fragmentation

Suppose I have a memory pool object with a constructor that takes a pointer to a large chunk of memory ptr and size N.  If I do many random allocations and deallocations of various sizes I can get the memory in such a state that I cannot allocate an M byte object contiguously in memory even though there may be a lot free!  At the same time, I can't compact the memory because that would cause a dangling pointer on the consumers.  How does one resolve fragmentation in this case?

Comment: Are you trying to implement an operating system or atleast a part of it? The only reason memory pool is preferred over normal allocation is because normal allocation deals with fragmentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wanted to add my 2 cents only because no one else pointed out that from your description it sounds like you are implementing a standard heap allocator (i.e what all of us already use every time when we call malloc() or operator new).

A heap is exactly such an object, that goes to virtual memory manager and asks for large chunk of memory (what you call "a pool"). Then it has all kinds of different algorithms for dealing with most efficient way of allocating various size chunks and freeing them. Furthermore, many people have modified and optimized these algorithms over the years. For long time Windows came with an option called low-fragmentation heap (LFH) which you used to have to enable manually. Starting with Vista LFH is used for all heaps by default.

Heaps are not perfect and they can definitely bog down performance when not used properly. Since OS vendors can't possibly anticipate every scenario in which you will use a heap, their heap managers have to be optimized for the "average" use.  But if you have a requirement which is similar to the requirements for a regular heap (i.e. many objects, different size....) you should consider just using a heap and not reinventing it because chances are your implementation will be inferior to what OS already provides for you.

With memory allocation, the only time you can gain performance by not simply using the heap is by giving up some other aspect (allocation overhead, allocation lifetime....) which is not important to your specific application.

For example, in our application we had a requirement for many allocations of less than 1KB but these allocations were used only for very short periods of time (milliseconds). To optimize the app, I used Boost Pool library but extended it so that my "allocator" actually contained a collection of boost pool objects, each responsible for allocating one specific size from 16 bytes up to 1024 (in steps of 4).  This provided almost free (O(1) complexity) allocation/free of these objects but the catch is that a) memory usage is always large and never goes down even if we don't have a single object allocated, b) Boost Pool never frees the memory it uses (at least in the mode we are using it in) so we only use this for objects which don't stick around very long.

So which aspect(s) of normal memory allocation are you willing to give up in your app?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the system there are a couple of ways to do it.

Try to avoid fragmentation in the first place, if you allocate blocks in powers of 2 you have less a chance of causing this kind of fragmentation. There are a couple of other ways around it but if you ever reach this state then you just OOM at that point because there are no delicate ways of handling it other than killing the process that asked for memory, blocking until you can allocate memory, or returning NULL as your allocation area.

Another way is to pass pointers to pointers of your data(ex: int **). Then you can rearrange memory beneath the program (thread safe I hope) and compact the allocations so that you can allocate new blocks and still keep the data from old blocks (once the system gets to this state though that becomes a heavy overhead but should seldom be done).

There are also ways of "binning" memory so that you have contiguous pages for instance dedicate 1 page only to allocations of 512 and less, another for 1024 and less, etc... This makes it easier to make decisions about which bin to use and in the worst case you split from the next highest bin or merge from a lower bin which reduces the chance of fragmenting across multiple pages.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing [object pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) for the objects that you frequently allocate will drive fragmentation down considerably without the need to change your memory allocator.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know more exactly what you are actually trying to do, because there are many ways to deal with this.
But, the first question is: is this actually happening, or is it a theoretical concern?

One thing to keep in mind is you normally have a lot more virtual memory address space available than physical memory, so even when physical memory is fragmented, there is still plenty of contiguous virtual memory.  (Of course, the physical memory is discontiguous underneath but your code doesn't see that.)

I think there is sometimes unwarranted fear of memory fragmentation, and as a result people write a custom memory allocator (or worse, they concoct a scheme with handles and moveable memory and compaction).  I think these are rarely needed in practice, and it can sometimes improve performance to throw this out and go back to using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

- write the pool to operate as a list of allocations, you can then extended and destroyed as needed. this can reduce fragmentation.
- and/or implement allocation transfer (or move) support so you can compact active allocations. the object/holder may need to assist you, since the pool may not necessarily know how to transfer types itself. if the pool is used with a collection type, then it is far easier to accomplish compacting/transfers.